# Finishing up an aurelia application

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia, jspm

I'm currently preparing to release my first [aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) based application. I've got nearly everything figured out, except some small details.

#### Loading css first

I found myself wanting to load some of the css before the application starts; specifically, animation logic for the loading div. I want this because otherwise the spinner won't spin. I know I can just include the spinner css separately, but I need (want) the animate lib anyway, so might as well add it. I've added the following to my index.html:

```
<link href="jspm_packages/github/daneden/animate.css@3.4.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="dist/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This feels wrong for two reasons. First, I can bundle this css with aurelia-bundler, so shouldn't I? And secondly, which actually brings me to my next question...

#### What goes in VC?

animate is in jspm_packages, which feels like it shouldn't be in version control. However, I do need the file. So, I could perhaps opt to copy the file to `dist/` in my build process. This question also applies to the `dist/` dir, which now contains the bundled files (made by aurelia-bundler) as well as my static assets (less to css, optimized images and minified json files), but also the source files used for dev (es2015-compiled files). The dist dir is in .gitignore as well as jspm_packages. Images get loaded from `dist/` and so do stylesheets. `index.html` isn't in dist, so I can't use relative paths and simply make a build directory. I'm a bit stuck here.

**Update**: Another example of a file that should be deployed, is `jspm_packages/system.js`. That's in jspm_packages, which isn't in version control.

Comment: I don't know what the "recommended" approach is so will be watching this with interest. I do know that `jspm bundle-sfx app/main.js app.js` creates an output distributable script file that can be included entirely on its own independent of SystemJS and jspm - https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree: jspm_packages and its contents should probably not be under source control during development.

But that does not stop you deploying those artefacts as part of a build process.  For example, my output directory for a deployable build would look something like:

```
/deploy
    /jspm_packages
        system.js
        system-polyfills.js
    app-bundle-vXXX-js
    config.js
    index.html
```

None of the above would be under my normal development version control.  Same goes for anything else generated (css from SASS/LESS, etc) and other 3rd party stuff that is not included in the bundle.

But that does not stop me generating a separate built/released/deployed versions of the above /deploy output (probably zipped or tarred ready to dump onto the deployment servers) if I need to keep track of versioned releases. In theory, I could recreate the build any time from the versioned source, but I might also want to store the versioned build output somewhere too.

Much depends on your approach to release management.

Comment: I'm currently copying one level deep into jspm_packages to dist, config, index and the bundle. This gives me a nice compact project. :)